# How can I check that a two dates are between a period(interval)?

Tags: java, date, jodatime

My input is a beginning date and an end date. And I want to check that it is between December 1 and March 31. (The year can change, and there will be only dates in, or dates outside this period).

So far I didn't found any solution with Joda-time. Can somebody give me a starting point how to do(not code, just the logic)?
I didn't checked the code yet, but it is VERY Ugly, and I want to find an algorithmic solution

```
public static boolean isInWinter(Contract contract) {
    logger.info("begin isInWinter:");
    DateTime beginDate = contract.getBeginningDate();
    DateTime endDate = contract.getEndDate();
    /*
     * If the year is different (etc 2012 dec,2013 marc) check that the
     * beginning month is december, and the end month is jan,feb,marc
     */
    if (endDate.getYear() - beginDate.getYear() == 1) {
        if ((beginDate.getMonthOfYear() == 12)
                && ((endDate.getMonthOfYear() == 1
                        || endDate.getMonthOfYear() == 2 || endDate
                        .getMonthOfYear() == 3))) {
            logger.info("return true different year");
            return true;
        }
        /*
         * Same year can be if begin and end date is december or begin and
         * and date is jan,febr,marc TODO REMOVE Auto formatter
         */
    } else if (endDate.getYear() - beginDate.getYear() == 0) {
        if ((beginDate.getMonthOfYear() == 12 && endDate.getMonthOfYear() == 12)
                || ((beginDate.getMonthOfYear() == 1
                        || beginDate.getMonthOfYear() == 2 || beginDate
                        .getMonthOfYear() == 3) && (endDate
                        .getMonthOfYear() == 1
                        || endDate.getMonthOfYear() == 2 || endDate
                        .getMonthOfYear() == 3))) {
            logger.info("return true same year");
            return true;
        }

    }
    logger.info("return false");
    return false;
}
```

Comment: can you provide whatever coding u have done till now

Comment: I don't want a code, just an algorithmic solution, my code is very ugly.

Comment: so if the input will be like 1 aug - 1 jan so the output will be NO.

Comment: Can you clarify? You have two dates (start/end) A & B, and would like to know if THAT date-span is inside your test span [December 1st to March 31], never mind the year? Then, what if A is inside and B is outside? Does the test period need to be fully inside your test-span, or does an intersection test sufic?

Comment: @MarkusMillfjord It won't be any input what A is inside and B is outside (it is in the specification). There can be only A and B inside or both outside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Joda-Time

[Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) and its [Interval](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Interval.html) class with the `overlap` method is just what you need. Very easy.

### Time Zone

Unlike java.util.Date, a DateTime truly knows its assigned time zone. Generally better to specify than rely on default. Note that if you are tracking date+time (a DateTime rather than a LocalDate), then time zone is critical. The definition of a "day" beginning and ending depends on time zone. Businesses that work across time zones may choose to use UTC for this purpose.

### Span of Time

FYI, besides Interval, Joda-Time also offers the Period and Duration classes for working with a span of time.

### Start of Day

When working with date-time values but focusing on a "day", then adjust the time portion to the first moment of the day for that particular time zone. In Joda-Time, simply call the `withTimeAtStartOfDay` method.

Avoid the "midnight"-related classes and methods. They are no longer recommended by the Joda-Time team.

### Half-Open

Joda-Time uses the "Half-Open" approach when comparing spans of time. The beginning in inclusive and the ending is exclusive. That means since you want from December 1 to March 31 that we define an Interval of `the first moment of the day of December 1` to `the first moment of the day of April 1`. If you ponder this, and search StackOverflow for other postings on "joda interval", you'll come to see the wisdom of this approach.

### Comparison

The Interval class offers handy comparison methods: [`contains`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/base/AbstractInterval.html#contains%28org.joda.time.ReadableInterval%29), `abuts`, `overlap`, and `gap`. Be sure to read the doc to understand exact details.

### java.time

Java 8 brings the new java.time package, inspired by Joda-Time, defined by JSR 310. Joda-Time continues to work in Java 8, but you may want to learn java.time rather than Joda-Time if you are new to date-time work.

### Example Code

```
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Budapest" ); // Or, perhaps DateTimeZone.UTC

// Inputs
DateTime contractStart = new DateTime( 2014, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, timeZone );
DateTime contractStop = new DateTime( 2014, 5, 6, 0, 0, 0, timeZone );
Interval contractInterval = new Interval( contractStart, contractStop );

// Target to test
DateTime targetStart = new DateTime( 2013, DateTimeConstants.DECEMBER, 1, 0, 0, 0, timeZone );
DateTime targetStop = targetStart.plusMonths( 4 );
Interval targetInterval = new Interval( targetStart, targetStop );

boolean targetContainsContract = targetInterval.contains( contractInterval );
boolean targetOverlapsContract = ( targetInterval.overlap( contractInterval ) != null );
```

Dump to console…

```
System.out.println( "contractInterval: " + contractInterval );
System.out.println( "targetInterval: " + targetInterval );
System.out.println( "targetContainsContract: " + targetContainsContract );
System.out.println( "targetOverlapsContract: " + targetOverlapsContract );
```

When run…

```
contractInterval: 2014-01-02T00:00:00.000+01:00/2014-05-06T00:00:00.000+02:00
targetInterval: 2013-12-01T00:00:00.000+01:00/2014-04-01T00:00:00.000+02:00
targetContainsContract: false
targetOverlapsContract: true
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an interval with the beginning and end date you get as inputs.

Create an interval going from March to December.

Your condition is true if either:

- the march to december interval entirely contains the input interval,
- or there is no overlap between the two intervals.

In code that would be:

```
marchToDecember.contains(interval) || marchToDecember.overlap(interval) == null
```

[Javadàoc for `Interval`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Interval.html)

Answer (score 1):

Since you mention that the dates will be either both in or both out the period, you'll only need to test one of them.

So just test whether `beginDate.getMonthOfYear()` returns either 12, 1, 2 or 3.