# java.util.date Format Conversion

Tags: java, date

The problem here is that i have the following code:

```
String newPattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS";
SimpleDateFormat formatterDB = new SimpleDateFormat(newPattern);
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

String nDate1 = rs.getString("FromDate");
String nDate2 = rs.getString("ToDate");
Date newDate1 = formatterDB.parse(nDate1);
Date newDate2 = formatterDB.parse(nDate2);

Date sd = formatter.parse("2013-08-22");
Date ed = formatter.parse("2013-08-24");
Date exd = formatter.parse("2013-08-23");
```

The first condition to be verified is that `exd` lies between [`sd,ed`] and if true then `exd` should also lie between [`newDate1,newDate2`] and if this is true then other elements from the dB will be fetched.

Please not that the source of both dates are different, one date is from the dB having a different format entirely whereas the other date is being given as a String input and they need to be compared, so they have got different format.

To make it more clear, here is an example:

> I gave input for `exd` as 2013-08-23 the input for `sd` and `ed` is given
>   the `newDate1` is 2013-08-28(in dB format) and `newDate2` is 2013-09-01(in
>   dB Format) Still it accepts the input `exd` and fetches the other
>   column.

** I have snipped the relevant code, for any issues, drop in a comment. Any Help is appreciated. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Given the variance in precision, how do you want to interpret, say, 2013-08-29 vs 2013-08-29 01:23:45.678?  Should they be equal (same date) or can 2013-08-29 be correctly interpreted as 2013-08-29 00:00:00.000?

Comment: they both should be considered as same dates, there is another entity in the db for time.

Comment: Are all the values coming from the same time zone?

Comment: Yes all values are in same time zone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use the java inbuilt date functionality.

Here is a small example :

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date date1 = sdf.parse("2009-12-31");
Date date2 = sdf.parse("2010-01-31");

if(date1.compareTo(date2)>0){
    System.out.println("Date1 is after Date2");
}else if(date1.compareTo(date2)<0){
    System.out.println("Date1 is before Date2");
}else if(date1.compareTo(date2)==0){
    System.out.println("Date1 is equal to Date2");
}else{
    System.out.println("How to get here?");
}
```

Edit : Example with respect to user's question

`exd` is `not between` newDate1 and newDate2 !!

```
public class DateCompare {

public static void main(String args[]) throws ParseException
{
    String newPattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS";
    SimpleDateFormat formatterDB = new SimpleDateFormat(newPattern);
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

    String nDate1 = "2013-08-29 11:11:11.000";
    String nDate2 = "2013-09-01 11:11:11.000";
    Date newDate1 = formatterDB.parse(nDate1);
    Date newDate2 = formatterDB.parse(nDate2);


    Date sd = formatter.parse("2013-08-22");
    Date ed = formatter.parse("2013-08-24");
    Date exd = formatter.parse("2013-08-23");


    //Comparing exd to sd and ed
    if(sd.compareTo(exd) * exd.compareTo(ed) > 0)
    {
        //comparing exd to newDate1 and newDate2
        if(newDate1.compareTo(exd) * exd.compareTo(newDate2) > 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Success : Now you can fetch data from DB !");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Oops ! Can't fetch data !");
        }
    }
  }
}
```

**Please note** that in this scenario, if the dates in different formats are compared, `if the dates are same, they won't return 0`, because of the `time factor` ! The time will also be compared and dates in `yyyy-MM-dd` format have `HH:mm:ss.SSS` all as `00:00:00.000`

Comment: the source of both dates are different, one date is from the dB having a different format entirely whereas the other date is being given as a String input and they need to be compared, so they have got different format. although the comparison thing might work. Thanks!

Comment: The date from DB can be fetched, converted to String and then compared !

Comment: In the snippet given nDate1 and nDate2 are from the dB directly. and there is another string sd and ed there which are given as string inputs the db format is the newPattern and the other is the string format

Comment: The format doesn't matter as long. As long as they are `Date type they can be compared`

Comment: I tried using your approach but the date which reflects after comparison is wrong it does not belong to the group specified.

Comment: @D3X please see the answer, I have edited it wrt to your question !

Comment: I have already used this approach, i saw it online before posting the question http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-compare-dates-in-java/ That is giving me a very odd result. I gave input for exd as 2013-08-23 the input for sd and ed is given the newDate1 is 2013-08-28(in dB format) and newDate2 is 2013-09-01(in dB Format) Still it accepts the input exd and fetches the other column.

Comment: See the new updated answer, all the values as specified in your comment. It doesn't fetch the data !

Comment: thanks! actually i was using exd.compareTo(newDate1). So it was giving an invalid response. I will just check if it fetches the dB data properly.

Comment: actually when now when i give a date within the range too it is not accepting, just tried it with real time data

Comment: Also, I dont want to consider the timings because, the time is basically the entity creation time which is of no use to me

Comment: @D3X if you are not concerned about time, you will have to reparse newDate1/newDate2 to yyyy-MM-dd using this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469507/how-can-i-change-the-date-format-in-java or make all the time as 0. You can use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7784067/compare-date-without-time

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way of dealing with the problem ....

```
int flag=0;    
  if(exd.compareTo(sd)>0 )
       if(exd.compareTo(ed)<0){
             System.out.println(exd+" Lies between"+ sd +"and"+ ed);  
             flag=1;
       } 
  /*convert from newPattern to "yyyy-MM-dd"*/
  SimpleDateFormat formatterDB = new SimpleDateFormat(newPattern);
  Date temp = formatterDB.parse(nDate1);
  SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
  String temp1 = formatter.format(temp);
  Date newDate1 = formatter.parse(temp1); 
  if(flag==1)
     if(exd.compareTo(newDate1)>0)
         if(exd.compareTo(newDate2)<0){
               /* your code to fetch other item from DB*/
         }
```

Comment: exd and newDate1 and newDate2 being in different formats are not getting compared and giving erroneous results. Anyway, good approach. Thanks!

Comment: I have added an approach for Date conversion method.

Comment: can you just check the example i posted.

Comment: Just To make it clear, nDate1 & nDate2 are in DB format (yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS) and exd is in "yyyy-MM-dd" format ? And You need to convert from default DB format to "yyyy-MM-dd" format ?
If so then use the above date conversion method .... it should work.

Answer (score 1):

## Short Answer

These two answers of mine have both the concepts and example code you need to neatly solve your problem:

- [Parsing strings into date-time objects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21748668/642706)
- [Using Interval objects to compare spans of time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21977337/642706)

## Date versus Date-Time

You have some date-only values and some date-time values. You need to make a decision as to what a date-only value means in relationship to the date-time.

One possibility is that a date-only is considered to be the first moment of the day, such as `2014-01-02 00:00:00`. Note that the time of first moment is *usually* `00:00:00`, but not necessarily because Daylight Saving Time (DST) or other anomalies could move the time. For example, `01:00:00`. Joda-Time will automatically adjust the time to first moment of day when parsing a date-only string into a date-time. But be aware that you can also call `withTimeAtStartOfDay` (ignore the "midnight"-related classes/methods as they are virtually deprecated by the creators).

Another possibility is that a date-only should be represented as a span of time, from first moment of the day to the first moment of the next day.

## Half-Open

Note that I am referring to the "Half-Open" approach where the beginning is inclusive and the ending is exclusive. Half-open generally works best for spans of time.

For more discussion and examples of Half-Open time spans, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21325595/642706) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20990737/642706) of mine.

## Parse First, Process Second

Get your date strings and date-time strings all parsed into date-time objects first. Once you have some reasonable objects in hand, then move on to your comparisons and business logic.

## Joda-Time

The java.util.Date and .Calendar classes are notoriously troublesome. Avoid them.

Instead use either the open-source library [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) or the new [java.time package](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) in Java 8.

Joda-Time offers three classes to handle a span of time: Period, Duration, and [Interval](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Interval.html). They include very handy methods of comparison, including `contains`, `abuts`, `overlap`, and `gap`.

### Search StackOverflow

Search for "joda interval" to find other examples.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just comparing two dates, where one has precision down to time, you should just truncate the time so both just represent Date.

Using Apache commons:

```
DateUtils.truncate(dateYouWantToTruncate, Calendar.Date);
```

Because your formatter is using ISO-8601 (year first, then month, then day), you can use the formatter you created to convert both dates to Strings and compare the strings.

```
formatter.format(sd).compareTo(formatter.format(newDate1));
```

You can also use the Calendar class.  It's fairly verbose, but would work.